# Почему toStringAsFixed(5) выводит на экран не 4321.12345, а 4321.12346?

Tags: dart, core

Почему toStringAsFixed(5) выводит на экран не 4321.12345, а 4321.12346?
print((4321.12345678).toStringAsFixed(5)); // 4321.12346
в чем причина почему игнорируется цифра 5?

Comment: А математика что на этот счет говорит? Не игнорируется, а округляется к большему. Пример из справки (точь в точь Ваш): `( 4321.12345678 ) . toStringAsFixed ( 5 ) ;   // 4321.12346 `

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек)))